# Taskill & program restart on multiple computers with Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, restart, taskkill

I am looking to kill and restart a specific task if it is anything other than running on multiple remote machines without using WinRM or pskill. I have come up with the following code.

When the task is running on *all* the machines, I will get

> computer1 Service is running,
> computer2 Service is Running,
> ...

When the service is not running (stuck in a pending state seems to be the biggest culprit) the script will error out.

If single target a machine by `#`ing out all the others, it will work just fine. I have another script that tells me what machines are running and what machines are not/pending.

```
$ComputerName = 
'computer1'
'computer2',
'computer3', 
'computer4',
'computer5',
'computer6',
'computer7',
'computer8'

Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName)
{
  $ServiceName = 'name'
  $ServiceInfo = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -ComputerName $ComputerName
  if ($ServiceInfo.status -eq 'Running') {
    Write-Host $Computer 'Service is Running'
  }
  While ($ServiceInfo.status -ne 'Running') {
    taskkill /s $ComputerName /IM 'ApacheWebServices.exe' /F
    Write-Host $ServiceInfo.Status
    $ServiceInfo | Set-Service -status Running
    Write-Host "Service starting"
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't dictate the status value of a service - but [you can _start_ it if need be](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-service?view=powershell-7.4).

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `Set-Service -status Running` is not "dictating the status" but one way of starting a service https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-service?view=powershell-7.4#example-4-start-a-service

Answer (score 0):

```
While ($ServiceInfo.status -ne 'Running') {
    taskkill /s $ComputerName /IM 'ApacheWebServices.exe' /F
    Write-Host $ServiceInfo.Status
    $ServiceInfo | Set-Service -status Running
    Write-Host "Service starting"
}
```

Will run into an endless loop of killing and starting the service because you never update the `$ServiceInfo`, thus `$ServiceInfo.status` will be stuck at whatever the initial reading was.

The least thing you need to add in this loop is

```
While ($ServiceInfo.status -ne 'Running') {
    taskkill /s $ComputerName /IM 'ApacheWebServices.exe' /F
    Write-Host $ServiceInfo.Status
    $ServiceInfo | Set-Service -status Running
    Write-Host "Service starting"

    # optionally, add some delay here before requesting a new status

    # Request a new service status
    $ServiceInfo = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName -ComputerName $ComputerName
}
```

or alternatively

```
While (...) {
  ...
  $ServiceInfo = ($ServiceInfo | Set-Service -status Running  -PassThru)
}
```

ie assign the result of your call to the `$ServiceInfo` variable again.

Furthermore you should probably also create some kind of failsafe. Ie, if the service can't be started after for instance 5 iterations of your loop, print an error message and continue to the next machine. Otherwise, if there is some permanent issue with one of the machines, your loop will be stuck forever until you fix that issue.

And typically with this kind of operations, you use some kind of backoff strategy. Ie after the first failed attempt, apply some timeout, before trying again. And for every failed attempt extend that timeout.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was going to try this out but everything was running as should this morning. I am going to do my due diligence for adding iterations and time outs. I am new to PowerShell , trying to learn as I go.